# Kendo UI Grid Scrolling locks up during datasource update

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid that keeps locking up **on iOS** if I accidentally scroll during a datasource update.

Is there a solution to this or does anyone know if this is a bug?
Do I need to stop all incoming events until the datasource refresh is complete?

Basically, I have a grid with some buttons that send data to the server. If I happen to scroll or press a button while the datasource's built-in spinner is cycling, then the whole grid locks up and is useless until I refresh the browser.